# Why is this syntax to generate parentheses in math mode awry?

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to wrap values in parentheses with

```
$\frac{\left (7-2)^8 \right \left (32-3)^5 \right}{5}$
```

However, pdflatex issues this error: `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).`

Why? Taking out the `\left` and `\right` tokens eliminates the error.

Comment: There's no need to add `\left` and `\right`, in general. The input `\frac{(7-2)^8 (32-3)^5}{5}` is what you need. Anyway, `\right` goes *before* the `)`.

Comment: After your first `right` you don't have a bracket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `\left` and `\right` mean that the delimiters immediately following them are  of *variable height:* TeX measures the formula between `\left` and `\right` and extends the delimiters so they completely envelop the expression.  Therefore if your expression is just one line with symbols of normal height, it is easier to omit them: `$(x+2)$`. This is the usual case with inline equations.  However, when you use displayed equations with large symbols, you need to have large delimiters: compare

```
\[
 (\sum_i x_i)
\]
```

and

```
\[
 \left(\sum_i x_i\right)
\]
```

Also, sometimes you need just one delimiter;  the standard device is to use an empty delimiter (dot, `.`) on the other end, for example

```
\[
 \left.  \frac{df}{dx} \right|_{x\to 0}
\]
```

Comment: It's not only easier, it's *correct* to omit `\left` and `\right`!

Comment: @egreg Some software that automatically produces tex code always inserts `\left` and `right`: I guess the authors think it is easier than to check the output.  For example, in Maxima `tex((x+y)*z);` produces `$$\left(y+x\right)\,z$$`

Comment: Well, that software is wrong. :)

Comment: @egreg depends on the definition of "wrong", I guess...